# How to change/switching between fa,far,fad or fas of font-awesome using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, font-awesome

### How to change `data-prefix`'s value

How we can change `data-prefix`'s value after add fa,far,fad or fas to class from `fontawesome.min.css` using javascript or jquery. Because, when we add fas,far or fa... we specify `data-prefix`'s value.
so to change fa,fas or fad... we can't change it from class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's ok, I made it !*

HTML :

```
<i id='#element' class='far fa-heart'></i>
```

JQUERY :

```
  // let change 'far' value to 'fas'
   $("#element").attr("data-prefix","fas");
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
document.getElementById("element").setAttribute("data-prefix","fas");
```

Comment: yep, sometimes ask to a colleague / coworker helps a lot

Comment: Yep, if you have. But, still to inspect on navigator, the best way to analyze your code and solve the problem.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for some reason.

`document.getElementById("leftIcon")` returns the element:
`<svg _ngcontent-htm-c18 id=​"leftIcon" class=​"svg-inline--fa fa-grin-squint fa-w-16 fa-2x" aria-hidden=​"true" focusable=​"false" data-prefix=​"far" data-icon=​"grin-squint" role=​"img" xmlns=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2000/​svg" viewBox=​"0 0 496 512" data-fa-i2svg data-perfix=​"fas">​…​</svg>​`
then running
`document.getElementById("leftIcon").setAttribute("data-perfix","fas")` changes nothing.

Comment: @NikitaFuchs maybe this happened because of:
- `fas` is not available for the icon you are using.
- You are using external API (It must be internal).

Comment: data-perfix should be data-prefix

Comment: @It'sJustaPrinterDriver I've fixed the typos now